# Recently Updated ownCloud now giving a blank screen

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, owncloud

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7, and PHP 5.5.9.

Recently updated ownCloud from 9.1.0 Stable, to whatever current version is in the repository. And when I request http://myserveraddress/owncloud I get a blank page. I checked my apache2 logs and I was getting the following error upon request of ownCloud (When I go the the aforementioned address).

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class OC_App in /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/app.php on line 55
```

When I go to the designated file at line 55 I see this:

```
class OC_App {
    static private $appVersion = [];
    static private $adminForms = array();
    static private $personalForms = array();
    static private $appInfo = array();
    static private $appTypes = array();
    static private $loadedApps = array();
    static private $altLogin = array();
    private static $shippedApps = null;
    const officialApp = 200;
```

I tried seeing if this issue has been solved by someone, but to no avail.

Comment: error message seems clear, what dont you understand?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I'm new to Ubuntu, thus I don't understand what the error message is saying/means. I realize now, that the repository that I'm using, since owncloud was taken off of the main Ubuntu repositories, was for a previous version and I'm doing a clean install of it.

Comment: nothing to do with Ubuntu its a php error. the class "OC_App" has already been declared